# Media query settings

Tags: html, css, media-queries, tablet

I created a media query for phones

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px), screen and (max-width: 480px)  {  ...css here... body {width:50%;}
```

but i need this query for desktop

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 750px), screen and (max-width: 750px)
```

if i add like to `@media` desktop query  `.body {width:100%;}` the settings is changed in 480px also.

My question is: How i separate `480px` css settings, and `750px` css settings to be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

method A:

write larger width queries before smaller so they can overwrite them

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px){
  body{
    width:100%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  body{
    width:50%;
  }
}
```

method B:

define min-width as well:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) and (min-width: 481px){
  body{
    width:100%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  body{
    width:50%;
  }
}
```

NOTE:i think that you dont need both `max-device-width` and `max-width`

Comment: Thank you it works! Please advise with mobile-landscape

Comment: `@media screen and (orientation:landscape)`